# Enabling permission to use cmd line "msg" without giving local admin

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I am attempting to allow a group of users to send a message using the "msg" command, i.e.

```
msg * /server:*machinename* Hello!
```

On the local machine on which I want them to send the message to, if I add them to the Remote Desktop User's group, they get the error "Error 5 getting session names".  If I add them to the local admin group, they're able to send the message.

Is there any other way I can give them permission to do this, such as via GPO, so that they don't have local admin privileges but can still send the message?  For those who might mention it, this has nothing to do with the RemoteRPC registry key being enabled; that's already been done.